# JavaScript - Maintain Object key value order

Tags: javascript, json, object

My required object key-value(property-value) Order : `{three:3,two:2,one:1}`

I want last added key at top,When i add key-value dynamically the order i got is given below,

```
var numObj={};   
numObj["one"]=1;   
numObj["two"]=2; 
numObj["three"]=3;  
console.log(numObj) // result i get is  { one:1, three:3,two:2 }
```

Please any one help me to get this key-value order {`three:3,two:2,one:1}`

[image]

Comment: If you need to preserve an order then you need to use an Array; the order of keys in an Object is not guaranteed by design.

Comment: There is no key order in JavaScript nor is there a way to enforce one.

Answer (score 2):

As the commenters point out, JavaScript objects have no defined order for iteration. However, JavaScript *maps* do: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map.

```
let aMap = new Map();
myMap.set('AKey1', 'AValue1');
myMap.set('AKey2', 'AValue2');
myMap.set('AKey3', 'AValue3');

for (let x of aMap) {
  console.log(x[1]);
}
```

Will provide

```
AValue1
AValue2
AValue3
```